# Efficient method to store int as string in c

Tags: c, arrays, int

I have an integer `int ThermoTemp=55` I need to convert it as string and store in `char Thermoprint[6]`

i just want it as `05.5,`

here is the code i have tried

```
 ThermoPrint[0]=((ThermoTemperature/100)+0x30);
 ThermoPrint[1]=(((ThermoTemperature/10)%10)+0x30);
 ThermoPrint[3]=((ThermoTemperature%10)+0x30);
 ThermoPrint[2]='.';
 ThermoPrint[4]=',';
```

is there any efficient method to do this?

Comment: You want `55` as `05.5`? Post your whole problem, i.e., what are you trying to do? A modular example of your issue will not fetch you good answers.

Comment: Is there a reason you are concerned about efficiency (especially given that what you have is likely to be pretty efficient)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
  sprintf(Thermoprint,"%02d.%d",ThermoTemp/10,ThermoTemp%10);
```

(thanks for the suggestion squeemish )

Comment: Now how in the world can he  store it in a `char` ?

Comment: @Acme what do you mean?

Comment: @Acme What? The question clearly states `char Thermoprint[6];` which is an array so it's perfectly fine to construct a string in there. I do think the array could be made slighly larger just to be on the safe side (or use `snprintf()`).

Comment: @Acme please read the question again .. he is asking to put this in a char array  .. not a char variable

Comment: @Acme no worries mate